# Django - filter query returns incorrect queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

Here is my `Vendor` model.

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    cluster = models.ManyToManyField(Cluster)
    name = models.CharField(_("vendor name"),max_length=30)
    phone = models.IntegerField(_("vendor phone no."),max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(_("vendor address"),max_length=70)
    objects = VendorManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

`cluster` is a `ManyToManyField` from `Vendor` to the `Cluster` model, which is as follows -

```
class Cluster(models.Model):
    clusterName = models.CharField(_("Locality name"),max_length=70)
```

Now, I run the following queries-

```
Vendor.objects.values('id','cluster').all()
```

This gives the result - `[{'cluster': 3, 'id': 2}, {'cluster': 3, 'id': 3}, {'cluster': 4, 'id': 3}]`

Clearly, the Vendors with id 3 is related to two clusters with ids 3 and 4 and the vendor with id 2 is associated with the cluster with id 2.

On running,

```
Vendor.objects.values('id','cluster').filter(cluster=3)`
```

I expected it to return `[{'cluster': 3, 'id': 2}, {'cluster': 3, 'id': 3}]`

However, it returns

```
[{'cluster': 3, 'id': 2}, {'cluster': 3, 'id': 3}, {'cluster': 4, 'id': 3}].
```

I'm not sure but this happens probably because `.filter()` finds the vendor id which correspond the cluster id 3, and then return all the QuerySets corresponding to that particular vendor id.

However, I want it to return only those queries which are mapped to that cluster id only.

Comment: try putting the `filter` clause before the `values` clause

Comment: Worked like a charm. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting the `filter` clause before the `values` clause

I'm not 100% sure why... curiously the docs say it doesn't matter:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

> The people who made Django prefer to put all the SQL-affecting methods first, followed (optionally) by any output-affecting methods (such as values()), but it doesn’t really matter. This is your chance to really flaunt your individualism.

I think your guess as to why may be correct